# How to wait and get value of Span object in Selenium Python binding

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, assertions, testcase

I have following code in my web page.

```
<div id="" class="user_acc_setails">
<ul id="accDtlUL">
<li>First Name: <span id="f_name">Anuja</span></li>
```

By the time page loading, the value for *Sapn* is not set. It will take very small time to set the value. I want to wait and get that value in my *Python* file.

I'm currently using following code,

```
element = context.browser.find_element_by_id('f_name')
assert element.text == 'Anuja'
```

But it gives me an ***AssetionError***. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to select an answer?

Answer (score 6):

Correct way it this case would be to use [Explicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) (see Python code there). So you need something like

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.Id,'f_name'), 'Anuja'))
```

Answer (score 4):

here's a function that does that;

```
def wait_on_element_text(self, by_type, element, text):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            ec.text_to_be_present_in_element(
                (by_type, element), text)
        )
```

Where by_type replace with e.g. By.XPATH, By.CSS_SELECTOR .
Where element replace with the element path - the elements xpath, unique selector, id etc.
Where text replace with the element's text e.g. the string associated with the element.

Answer (score 1):

```
url = "http://..."
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    present = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "myclassname"), "valueyouwanttomatch"))
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("myclassname")
    print elem.text
finally:
driver.quit()
```

I realized that the return object of `wait.until` is not an elem but a boolean variable, so I have to recall the locate element again.

Comment: How do you get `text_to_be_present_in_element` if the class name is repeated, but the text is different? As a workaround, I've been using `presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "repeatclassname"))`, but I would prefer referencing the location of the repeated class, with a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. May be this is not the correct way. What I have done is used Python sleep before finding element and Assert it's value.

```
import time
...

time.sleep(3)
element = context.browser.find_element_by_id('f_name')
assert element.text == 'Anuja'
```

Then it is working perfectly.

Comment: No it isn't, explicit waits are the answer to your problem: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

### You can use browser.implicitly_wait(2) command to wait browser implicitly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
```

Comment: this does nothing but decrease the default implicit wait